# LINQ to SQL uses CONVERT when calling my Stored Procedure

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I like to use with LINQ to SQL. I got it added to dbml just fine and manage to call it but then the weird stuff happens. I'm getting the "Cannot find either column "MySchema" or the user-defined function or aggregate "MySchema.pi_MyStoredProcedure", or the name is ambiguous." -error. Tried to figure out why this is happening since I can execute the proc just fine from SSMS. SQL Profiler managed to catch the query and it was like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CONVERT(Int,[MySchema].[pi_MyStoredProcedure](@p0)) AS   [value]',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'ParameterValue'
```

I get the same "cannot find..." -error from SSMS when I try to execute this. I suspect this may have something to do with the return type of my stored proc. I had to set it by hand in the .dbml XML code. That looks like this:

```
<Function Name="MySchema.pi_MyStoredProcedure" Method="pi_MyStoredProcedure" IsComposable="true">
    <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(512)" />
    <Return Type="System.Int32" />
</Function>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Every online tutorial I've managed to find tell me to do this but obviously there's something else I'm missing? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the Stored Procedure to use OUTPUT parameter instead of RETURN.